# Helping solve the Bernoulli differential equations $y'=2y-e^x y^2$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I’m trying to solve this differential equation that I think is to be solved with Bernoulli

> $y'=2y-e^xy^2$

I tried to follow the various steps to bring it to a shape that would allow me to get a general solution in the format so a first order linear differential equation

> $y(x)=e^{-A(x)}[\int e^{A(x)} b(x)dx+c]$

But I can not proceed. Could you help me by explaining how to solve it?

This is the steps I've made:

> $y'=2y-e^xy^2 \space | \space \alpha=2 $

So I divided every value for $-y^2$ and substact $2y$

> $ -\frac{y'}{y^2}+\frac{2}{y}=e^x$ with $Z=y^{-2}$

At this point I made the derivative of $Z \rightarrow\space Z'=-\frac{2}{y^3}y' \rightarrow -\frac{1}{2}Z'$

> $-\frac{1}{2}Z'+\frac{1}{y}Z=e^x$

Multiply and divide by -2 both sides

> $-2*\frac{1}{2}Z'+\frac{2}{y}Z=e^x * -2$

So as to get

> $Z'+\frac{1}{x}Z=-2e^x$
> Which is a first order linear differential equation

Thank you very much.

Comment: Have you tried substituting $u=y^{-1}$? You should show us what exactly you've tried.

Answer (score 1):

Try $u=y^{-1}$, as in the comment.
Then we have $u'=-y'/y^2$.
Could you try to express your original equation in terms of $u$ and $u'$?

Comment: Why $u=y^{-1}$?

Comment: Because it works. This is motivated by noticing $y'/y^n$ has an anti-derivative of $y^{-{n+1}}$ up to some constant factor. Similarly, you would use $u=\ln y$ to deal with $y'/y$.

Answer (score 0):

$$
\begin{align}
\dfrac {dy}{dx} &= 2y-e^x y^2 \\
\dfrac {dy}{dx} -2y &= -e^x y^2  \\
y^{-2} \dfrac {dy}{dx}  -2y^{-1} &= -e^x  \\
\text { now let } y^{-1} &= t \\
\implies -y^{-2} dy &= dt \\
-\dfrac {dt}{dx}-2t &= -e^x \\
\text {now,} te^{2x} &= \int e^x e^{2x} dx \\
y^{-1}e^{2x} &= \dfrac {e^{3x}}3 + k \\
\end{align}
$$

Comment: For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: Thank for your solution! I rewrite your solution in MathJax, is this right? $y'=2y-e^x y^2 \\
y'-2y=-e^x y^2 \\
y^{-2} y'-2y^{-1}=-e^x\\
y^{-1} =t\\
-y^{-2} dy=dt \\
-t'-2t=-e^x \\
t*e^{2x}= \int (e^x *e^{2x})dx\\
(y^{-1})*e^{2x}=\frac{e^{3x}}{3}+ k $

Comment: You can also directly edit the question. You can split into blocks with multiple display equations and text with (short) text formulas. A multiplication sign is rarely used, if you want it use `a\cdot b` $a\cdot b$.